# How to find the maximum and minimum values of a function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

I am given $\alpha = \sin \theta \cos \phi$ and $\beta =\sin \theta \sin \phi$.

How should I proceed to find the maximum and minimum values for the below function subject to the constraint $x^2 +y^2 \leq 1$:
$$f(\theta, \phi, x, y) =(\alpha x+\beta y)\left(x^2 +y^2 -2(\alpha x+\beta y)^2\right)$$

Also, what is the point which attains the maxima/minima?

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Look up `Minimize` or `NMinimize` or the equivalent `Maximize` functions in the documentation. Try to express your functions in MMA code. Try to use those minimizers, then come back with any specific issues you run into.

Comment: @MarcoB I tried the following:
Maximize[{(ax+by) (y^2 + x^2) -2 (ax^2 + by^2)^2 , x^2 + y^2 <= 1, a=sin(p)cos(q),b=sin(p)sin(q)}, {x, y}]

It is saying no global maxima

Comment: @wanderer 1) you're missing some spaces in there. It should read `a x + b y` for example. 2) In Mathematica you use `[ ]` for function calls, not `( )` so it's not `sin(p)`  but `Sin[p]`. 3) You should not do the assignment of a,b inside the maximize, and 4) you are not constraining theta or phi and are not maximizing over those at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f[θ_, ϕ_, x_, y_] := (* here we set u = {α, β} *)
 With[{u = Sin[θ] {Cos[ϕ], Sin[ϕ]}, v = {x, y}},
  (u . v)*(v . v - 2 (u . v)^2)]
Minimize[{f[θ, ϕ, x, y], 0 <= θ <= 2 π, 
  0 <= ϕ <= 2 π, x^2 + y^2 <= 1}, {θ, ϕ, x, y}]
Maximize[{f[θ, ϕ, x, y], 0 <= θ <= 2 π, 
  0 <= ϕ <= 2 π, x^2 + y^2 <= 1}, {θ, ϕ, x, y}]
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working well. Just a follow up question, If I want to optimize the absolute value of the function, what do I use? Is there an abs function or anything similar?

Comment: Also,  when i changed the limit from $2\pi$ to $\pi$, I  did not get a solution.

What I got is this:

Minimize[{(x Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]]+y Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]]) (x^2+y^2-2 (x Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]]+y Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]])^2),0<=\[Theta]<=\[Pi],0<=\[Phi]<=\[Pi],x^2+y^2<=1},{\[Theta],\[Phi],x,y}]

Comment: @wanderer yes it's just `Abs`. Please search [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/) and have a read, as it sounds like you are very new to Mathematica. For the other question, I'm not sure why that happens, but try using the numerical methods `NMaximize` and `NMinimize` instead of `Minimize`/`Maximize`.